# how to change the image button, that causes to collapse/expand the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to change the image button, that causes the div to collapse/expand.

for example clicking "+" will expand. While  expanding, "+" becomes "-". Again, clicking on "-" will collapse the div as well as "+" will appear again.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksen/zd57W/)

html:

```
  <div class="expandContent"><a><img id="arrow" src="http://s13.postimg.org/myy6y2uxv/plus.png"></a></div>

<div class="showMe" style="display:none">This content was hidden, but now shows up </div>
```

js:

```
 $('.expandContent').click(function(){
    $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: check this example http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/3R2Jd/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8YWab/)</kbd>

```
var div_show = $('.showMe'), //cache selectors
    arrow = $('#arrow');
$('.expandContent').click(function () {
    div_show.slideToggle('slow', function () { //slideToggle callback function -> when slideToggle  finishes.
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) { //if div is visible change image to minus 
            arrow.prop('src', 'http://www.a1registry.ca/en/images/minus.png');
        } else { // if div hidden change image to plus
            arrow.prop('src', 'http://s13.postimg.org/myy6y2uxv/plus.png');
        }
    });
});
```

---

References

[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#slideToggle-duration-easing-complete)

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zd57W/2/

```
    $("#one,#two").on("click", function(){
        $("#one,#two").slideToggle();
        $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I must have asked earlier, then it could have saved me past 3 hours!, sorry i was not allowed to comment before 2hrs because of low reputation. again very very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.expandContent').click(function () {
     $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
     $('#arrow').toggleClass('plus minus');
 });
```

CSS:

```
#arrow{display:block;height:9px;width:9px;}
.plus{background:url(http://s13.postimg.org/myy6y2uxv/plus.png);}
.minus{background:url(http://s13.postimg.org/myy6y2uxv/plus.png);}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/zd57W/3/)

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/rUz2C/2/) is a fiddle.

HTML

```
<div id='clickme'>+</div>
<div id='imagediv' class='imagediv'></div>
```

CSS

```
#clickme {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}
.imagediv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
globalsize = 1;
$('#clickme').click(function(){
  if (globalsize == 1)
    {
     $('#imagediv').css( 'width', '200px' );
     $('#clickme').text( '-' );
     globalsize = 2;
     } else {
     $('#imagediv').css( 'width', '100px' );
     $('#clickme').text( '+' );         
     globalsize = 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQueryUI and the buttons that come with it (see jFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zd57W/5/)

```
<div class="expandContent ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin"></div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">This content was hidden, but now shows up</div>


$('.expandContent').click(function(){
        $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
         $(this).toggleClass('ui-icon-zoomin ui-icon-zoomout')
    });
```

Regards
Hendrik